# aws cli cloudformation update-stack set tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I need to update the tags for a AWS cloudformation stack only.

Unfortunately you cannot do:

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --tags <tags>
```

Does anyone know the best process for this?

If i do:

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --use-previous-template --template-body <JSON blob>
```

Will the template body be added to the previous template, overwriting previous values?

Is it possible to download the live cloudformation JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I did it:

You can update the tags only by get the information from the api and piping back into your update_stack request. Right before you update the stack, you append the the tags list/array with the new dict/object you want.

Here is an example using python. As long as you know the tags you want to add, this will update your stack, keep everything the same, but just update your tags list/array with added tags.

```
import boto3
import botocore.errorfactory
client = boto3.client("cloudformation")
response = client.describe_stacks(StackName="arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:012345678901:stack/<stackname>/asdf1234-as12-df34-gh56-qwerty012345")
responsetemplate = client.get_template(StackName="arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:012345678901:stack/<stackname>/asdf1234-as12-df34-gh56-qwerty012345")
response["Stacks"][0]["TemplateBody"] = responsetemplate["TemplateBody"]
response["Stacks"][0].pop("StackId", None)
response["Stacks"][0].pop("Description", None)
response["Stacks"][0].pop("CreationTime", None)
response["Stacks"][0].pop("StackStatus", None)
response["Stacks"][0].pop("EnableTerminationProtection", None)
response["Stacks"][0].pop("DriftInformation", None)
if "LastUpdatedTime" in response["Stacks"][0]:
    response["Stacks"][0].pop("LastUpdatedTime", None)

Tags={
            'Key': 'Namefirstest',
            'Value': 'somevalue'
        }
response["Stacks"][0]["Tags"].append(Tags)
# print(response["Stacks"][0].keys())


update = client.update_stack(**response["Stacks"][0])
print(update)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the updating only the tags via cli. However its very easy to do this in the aws console.

updating the stack by providing a new JSON template will override the previous template.

you can download the template by using the dashboard (CFN->template tab) or by using the [cli command get-template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/get-template.html)

Comment: as far as i can tell the cli 'get-template' call does not have all the information filled in which was entered during setup, e.g. the resources are missing. Is there a way to get this? A way to flush the current config to JSON?

Comment: @norm - Do you mean the parameters you've entered? (I think there's an API for that too).  The 'get-template' API will return the same JSON template you've provided when creating the stack. What resources are missing? What do you mean by config?

Comment: As far as i could see there was no API for flushing the active config. There is a describe-statcks API but this produces a JSON document which is insufficient to re-create the live stacks -  meaning it is an incomplete flush of the config. Perhaps there is no way to do this.